# Adding a number if file exists PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to see if a certain file exists. If it does, I need to make it look like #_filename.jpeg. It works, but only adds a 1 and does not increment further.

This is my code:

```
if (file_exists('upload/'.$file_name)) {
    $i = 1;
        while(file_exists('upload/'/$i."_".$file_name)) {
            $i++;
        }
    $file_name = $i."_".$file_name;
}
```

Comment: what is it doing with sql !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have syntax error (missing `.`) so your while condition not working and not going to loop so `$i` not increases try to replace

```
while(file_exists('upload/'/$i."_".$file_name)) {
```

to

```
while(file_exists('upload/'.$i."_".$file_name)) {
```

Comment: Thanks a ton that fixed it. Its amazing how something that small can cause so much headache haha! Thanks